# SQL update one column to max value without keys

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have the following data in a table

```
ID  name   code    number
621 eric   10PT    1
676 eric   10PT    1
679 eric   10PT    1
```

I need to write an update statement that updates the ID to the max value for this specific group of data. The columns aren't keys and the entire table doesn't contain any key seither

Result:

```
ID  name   code    number
679 eric   10PT    1
679 eric   10PT    1
679 eric   10PT    1
```

I forgot to add that the table has more of these groups. The update statement has to cover all groups at once.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Also, which fields determine a specific group?

Comment: MSSQL server 2014. The ID, name, code and number determine a specific group. there are more colums in the table but these determine the group.

Comment: Please can you accept my answer if it helps you? i will delete this comment later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such a case I would use a `CTE` in order to do the `UPDATE`:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT ID, 
          MAX(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY name, code, number) AS max_ID
   FROM mytable
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET ID = max_ID
```

The `UPDATE` is propagated to the actual records in the database. The `CTE` uses windowed version of `MAX` in order to get the maximum `ID` value within each `name, code, number` group.

Comment: This is brilliant, works like a flaw. Thanks! Some of the columns that are in the PARTITION BY can contain NULL values, which creates additional partitions. I don't want that. I'm not sure how to ignore NULL values in the PARTITION BY statement. Any idea?

Comment: @ImperialBert How do you want to handle `NULL`s? Completely ignore them? Then include a `WHERE` clause to filter those records out. Otherwise, can you specify a use case along with expected result?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I would like to ignore NULL values. For example, if name and code are the same, but number is NULL, this partition should still be updated to the max_ID. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @ImperialBert What if you have values like `(name, code, number) = ('eric', '10PT', 1), ('eric', '10PT', 2), ('eric', '10PT', null)`. How can we find a matching partition for the last record in this case?

Answer (score 3):

```
Update t1
set id=t2.maxid 
from mytable t1
inner join 
(select max(id)as maxid,name, code, number from mytable group by name, code, number) t2
on t2.name=t1.name and t1.code=t2.code and t2.number=t1.number
```

Comment: Same as the other query, there is no group determination in it.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE TABLE tableName SET ID=MAX(ID)
```

Comment: There is no group determination in this query. So, it will fail in cases more the one groups exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a sub query and cross join to update the id field

```
update t set id = m.mid
from myTable t 
cross apply (select max(id) as mid from myTable) m
```